# Read data directly from mongodb via useAsyncData in nuxt 3

Tags: mongodb, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to query mongodb in my nuxt app. I've done it before in next.js using `getServerSideProps`, however when trying this in nuxt, using `useAsyncData` in my setup script, I get the following error in the browser:

```
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

We've simplifying this as much as possible, even importing only MongoClient directly (not using our database service wrapper), however just by instatiating the client we get this error.

How can we run our database logic before our component renders without writing a dedicated api endpoint?
We're using nuxt3, and vite

I just set up a new test project, with this code, and it doesn't work

app.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <pre>
      {{ data }}
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
const { data, error } = useAsyncData(
  async () => {
    const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    return { data: 'anything' }
  }
)
</script>
```

nuxt.config.ts

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({ })
```

Comment: Provide an example of how you query data from the mongo. A detail process

Comment: @ReaganM I can't even instantiate a client, let alone query data. Even just including: const client = new MongoClient() in the function causes an error, I'm assuming due to vite trying to polyfil the entirety of mongo as it tries to run it on the browser, despite it only being inside that function?

Comment: I have a database wrapper class I normally use that works fine, and we use that on the backend endpoints fine and it works ok. But when trying to use that in the frontend we get these errors. I tried to simplify it and get to the cause of the error by creating a client in the function directly, and it looks like it's just mongodb itself?

Comment: Is there any reasons why you are not using mongoose module for your nuxt project? I've been using mongoose for my nuxt projects and so far I don't encounter any issues with it.

Comment: I don't have a need for mongoose. I'm just using the mongodb driver directly combined with Typescript types and it works fine, shared across multiple apps/microservices. Regardless, mongoose uses mongodb under the hood. I doubt that'd fix this. But if it works for you maybe something else could be the cause?

Comment: @ReaganM Could you share the example of how you use mongoose? I just tried creating a bare minimum nuxt app using npx nuxi init, and importing MongoClient, and it doesn't work

Comment: I published a basic CRUD operations on github. I am trying to improve my typscript knowledge so I use typescript for it. Hope this helps you
https://github.com/ReaganM02/nuxt3-mongodb-crud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `useAsyncData` does.
It's is simply a way to load resources asynchronously with the ability to block navigation until the data is loaded. It's not `getServerSideProps`, which runs on the server. Instead, it runs before navigation.
So it can run on the server if we are loading the page for the first time, but it will run **on the client** if we are navigating to the page from another one.

I don't know any ways to colocate server and client code in Nuxt 3. I can only suggest looking into [tRPC Nuxt](https://trpc-nuxt.vercel.app/), which simplifies api generation, and allows for typesafe fetching.

Comment: Ahh damn, yeah you are correct that I assume that that's what useAsyncData does. I was looked through the docs and it appeared to be the equivalent, but I suppose that's not the case...